# .NET Regex to accept all digits and chars in a .Match call

Tags: .net, regex

Playing around with it in linqpad, I can't seem to get this to work. This is the raw business logic of my concern here. Notice that there is a business requirement:

> You have one string provided to regex.Match that will return the first match to compare against the test value. The test value will be input by the user as "12345" or "ABCDE" (a five digit alphanumeric string). If they enter six or more characters, or use invalid characters, those should be stripped to take the rightmost 5 characters.

```
void Main()
{
  var r = @"^(?:[^\p{L}\\<>~=,-]|[A-Za-z0-9])+$";
  var rg = new Regex(r);
  var test = "J99-291-098";
  var m = "91098";
  rg.Match(test).Dump();

  //(m == rg.Match(test).Captures[0].Value).Dump();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? All I want to capture is the `J99291098` of the example (and more specifically the `91098` of the test string, but if you can get me to `J99291908` I can figure out how to get just five).

I can't change the code to use Regex.Replace, I can't change the code to use more loops. If it's impossible to do this with just a Regex.Match then that's the answer, but I figure this can be done.

Comment: It is unclear what you need...

Comment: And yet somebody else answered the question. So ...

Comment: It is unclear what you need (2).

Comment: I don't see how anything in this question is unclear.  It is a simple question about using a built-in C# object, `Regex`.  If I had more regex-fu I would attempt an answer.

Comment: @Max - It might be a C# object, but regular expression engine's roughly share the same foundation for all languages. But, there is nothing stopping Microsoft from making a AppendToString method that itterates in a loop over the capture arrays. Something like CopyTo(Array,Ndx) except it appends to a string.

Comment: @sln did I give sample code and the environment it's running in? Did I not explain the business requirements? If you think this is vague, and someone has already given an answer, and I've provided build rules, then you tell me what's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No !!**, its not going to do all that stripping for you in one go.

What you have to do is match the chars of interrest, append to a string, then trim the
string for the last 5 chars.

I don't know what you mean by more loops. Using `Match` or `Matches` there will be a loop involved.
Match just gets the first match and stops. Have to do the next Match untill no match.
Matches gets all the matches in one call, but you still have to iterate over the MatchCollection.

Here's some code if it helps.

```
        string input = "J99-291-098";
        string output = "";

        Regex rxTest = new Regex( @"([A-Za-z0-9]+)" );
        MatchCollection All_matches = rxTest.Matches( input );
        foreach (Match match in All_matches)
            output += match.Groups[1].Value;

        int nn; 
        if ( (nn=output.Length) > 0)
        {
            nn -= 5;
            nn = nn > 0 ? nn : 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Matched  {0}", output.Substring( nn ) );
        }

        return;

 // Output:  Matched  91098
```

Edit Another approach:

Using a single match, here is how to get just the characters you are interrested in.

```
  Regex rxTest = new Regex(@"^(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Za-z0-9]+))*[^A-Za-z0-9]*$");
  CaptureCollection cc1 = rxTest.Match(input).Groups[1].Captures;
```

How you get  the data from `cc1` is up to you.

Comment: You have succinctly captured the essence of "I can not add more loops" and ignored it. I understand that it would be quite easy to add more code, I'm trying to find a way to do it without modifying the code.

Comment: @icolebrand - Unfortunately, you didn't read the first word of my answer. Its **NO** you can't. **ALL** regular expressions accumulate match data in array structures, there are NO exceptions. Don't think you can pick and choose what to match without capturing parenthesis. Its an upside down tree of overlapping captures. **Everything** that you match ends up in the tree, there are no exceptions, ever!! If you are restricted to using just `Match`, I've edited to show how to get CaptureCollections.

Comment: Oh I read the first line. I just am waiting to see if anyone else has an answer that shows it can be done. And I'm curious who downvoted, as this is a solid answer to the question.